# how do i get the current url of qwebengineview in pyqt5 python?

Tags: python, pyqt5

So guys currently i'm working on a small web browser on python in PyQt5 but I want to get the current URL of the webpage on the QWebEngineView widget.
I try:

```
webEngineView.url()
```

But no such luck. remember that I am using PyQt5, NOT PyQt4.
Can somebody help me?
What I mean is, I need the attribute of QWebEngineView, which is the URL of the widget.

Comment: The `url` property is the right one, so if you're not getting it you're probably trying to use it in the wrong way or the wrong moment. Without a [mre] we cannot really help you more.

Answer (score 0):

`.url()` returns a QUrl object. Call `toString()` on the QUrl to get the raw Url.

`webEngineView.url().toString()`

[Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html)